# A mathematical issue in the resolution of Bell's spaceship paradox

Tags: special-relativity

I am referring to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_spaceship_paradox

and explanations based on diagrams like

[image: equal time and proper length]

The reasoning for a resolution of Bell's spaceship paradox is mainly that the definition of equal time slices for the two observers and therefore their distance calculations yield different results, i.e

$$ L \neq \ell_{AB} \neq \ell_{BC} $$

Whereas this is certainly true, it somehow misses the point.

The thread has to be accelerated as well, so let's introduce small rockets for each infinitesimal piece of the thread. All points on the thread feel the same acceleration, and for all infinitesimally neighboured pairs of points on the thread we can calculate their mutual distance.

Now the straight lines from the blue to the red spaceship are replaced by a *curve*, defined via infinitesimal equal time lines between infinitesimally separated points on the thread.

Therefore the straight line AB is replaced by a curve from A to some new point X on the red worldline. I think that the invariant length of *this* curve $\ell_{AX}$ is what really matters.

In the very end, that will lead to the same conclusion, namely that

$$ L \neq\ell_{AX} $$

and that the thread will break, simply b/c the math used also applies to infinitesimally separated spaceships. But I think it's worth mentioning.

What do you think?

Comment: I have been trying to get my head around the "Spaceship & String" scenario, and I have to admit it is currently beyond my competence to resolve ;)  I have a simple mentality: "we use inertial frames to do analysis when we can because the physics there is simpler".  As far as I can tell all "resolutions" refer to non-inertial frames.  Is there an analysis anywhere that resolves this _purely in terms of an inertial frame_ (like you can resolve whizzing a heavy weight around your head until the string breaks _without_ resorting to the "fictitious" centrifugal force)?

Comment: If you want to tease out the principles, just consider three or four points on the string.

Comment: @MarcoOcram BTW I am currently looking at this: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath817/kmath817.htm.  As to the other explanations, I find it frustrating that there is more effort put into explaining the string than the rockets (their length, position of engines etc.).  I mean, the string would just burn right? ;)

Comment: @MarcoOcram – the position of the string is usually not discussed, so I can't consider points on the string; my approach is about an idea how to fix the position of the string between the endpoints

Comment: @m4r35n357 In physics we try not to get hung up on practical engineering problems. We could for example have two rockets at the front connected by a transverse rod with the string attached to the middle of the rod so that the rocket flames do not impinge on it or make the string out of asbestos. For example, we can in principle ask what the gravitational potential is 100 km below the Earth's surface, without getting too hung up on the fact that any observer would get crushed or burnt. Those 'details' belong in the engineering forum.

Answer (score 1):

Bell’s paradox has a simple explanation.  If the pilots are told to accelerate together by providing the same constant thrust, the rockets and string are seen to contract as a unit.  There is a Lorentz rotation in space time that foreshortens their projection in the stationary frame.  The rotation  makes the back ship look like it accelerates more and the front ship accelerate less.

Bell tells the pilots to make it look to us that you do not have this extra apparent acceleration.  To do that, the front rocket needs to accelerate a bit more than the back rocket.  At the end of accelerating, if the separation in the rest frame is still L, then the separation in the rocket frame is $\gamma$ L > L, so of course the string breaks.

Comment: My point is that an equal time slice from one spaceships to the other is rather pointless. One has to construct a n equal time slice at each single point in between.

Comment: The L at the top of diagram should be L/$\gamma$ long and the string should not break if both rockets have exactly the same thrust.  The diagram that you drew is one in which the rockets have different thrusts, so the string breaking is not paradoxical.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to come to terms with is the notion of Born Rigid Motion. This is a form of acceleration that allows a long object to accelerate in such a way that it maintains constant length from the point of view of an observer riding on the object. To do this properly each part of the object requires its own rocket. Hypothetically we can say we have small rockets attached to each part of the string. When a object is accelerated like this, then an inertial observer watching the object accelerate would see it getting shorter as it accelerates. That would result in the worldlines of the object endpoints getting closer together (unlike in your diagram), so this ideal process is obviously not happening in the case illustrated by your diagram..

To maintain a constant length as in your diagram, the rocket at the front has to accelerate faster than the rear rocket and the object is stretched and would be measured to be getting longer as measured by someone riding on the object (who is at rest with object). The rear rocket would see and measure the front rocket to be moving away from him and just like in every day life, if you move one end of a piece string away from the other end, it gets stretched and eventually breaks.

A slight variation on the thought experiment is to connect the rockets with a tape measure with the a free wheeling spool attached to one rocket. They are instructed to maintain the same constant separation as seen by the inertial observer that does not accelerate. As they accelerate, the observers on the rocket will see the spool feeding out more and more tape, for as long as they keep accelerating, giving a visual proof to everyone that the proper distance between the two rockets is really increasing.

> All points on the thread feel the same acceleration

Here is an analogy. Imagine you are in a tall skyscraper. At the top you would measure a slightly lower acceleration due to gravity than at the base of the tower. The build maintains constant height despite the difference in proper acceleration between the top and the base. Now if we attach large rockets to the top of the building, while leaving the base connected to the ground in an attempt to make the proper acceleration at the top equal to that at the base, then the building will be stretched or broken. Maintaining constant proper length in an accelerating scenario requires that the different parts experience different proper acceleration (more at the back).

A good way to get more detail and intuition is by looking at the [Rindler coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates). In this system the observers following the curved hyperbolic curves maintain the same proper separation indefinitely as measured by their own rulers or by radar measurements. This is despite the fact they all have different proper accelerations, just like the observers in the skyscraper.

> My point is that an equal time slice from one spaceships to the other
> is rather pointless. One has to construct a n equal time slice at each
> single point in between. – TomS

We could tie a long string to a tree and the other end to a tractor and ask the tractor to drive away from the tree. We can calculate the tension in the string at any instant just by measuring the separation between the ends at any moment, without the need to calculate time slices. The Bell's rocket paradox is no different.

Answer (score 0):

The string is an irrelevance- it is included just to make the scenario more vivid. You can instead just ask whether the distance between the rockets increases in their instantaneous rest frame, the answer to which is yes. I suspect that if you wanted to model the behaviour of the string rigorously, it would be a complicated matter, so I think you are correct in assuming that the explanations we usually encounter are simplifications.

Comment: That is clear, but *not* my concern. You cannot have a straight line between the rockets and treat this as *their* instantaneous rest frame. A straight line from (t,x) on the worldline of the first rocket meets the worldline of the second rocket in some point with T>t. But for the speeds we have v(T) > v(t), so the straight line does not fit to the  restframe of the second rocket in T. That’s all I am saying. A string between the two rockets such that it defines local rest frames along itself means that the string is curved. This string could would also break.

Comment: I think we are talking at cross purposes because I have not made myself sufficiently clear. What I meant to say was that to show that the string would break, it is sufficient to show the the distance between the rockets increases.

Comment: I agree that if the string is made to accelerate at a constant rate in its initial rest frame, each part of the string will be moving at different speeds in a frame moving with any part of the string.

Comment: Great. I‘ll try to provide an explicit  construction.